# i need to use slidetoggle for all the elements

Tags: jquery, html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.start").next().slidetoggle("li");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="width:500px;" class="siblings">
  <ul>ul (parent)  
    <li class="start">li (sibling with class name "start")</li>
    <li>li (the next sibling of li with class name "start")</li>
  </ul>   
  <ul>ul (parent)  
    <li class="start">li (sibling with class name "start")</li>
    <li>li (the next sibling of li with class name "start")</li>
  </ul>   
</div>
```

This code is not working. I need to use slide toggle for all elements with parent-child relationship

Comment: What does `.slidetoggle("li")` supposed to do? Please take a look at [.slideToggle() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/). You can pass the duration of the animation to it as parameter and an optional callback function. So you can use `.slidetoggle("slow")`, `.slidetoggle("fast")` or `.slidetoggle(400)`(which is 400 millisecond)

Comment: millisecond is not a problem bro... check out the answers..it still works with slidetoggle(250)...

Comment: Why are you posting different answers? Do you know what answer section is used for? also since JavaScript is case sensitive then `.slidetoggle();` is wrong and you have to use `.slideToggle();`  as you have in your answers(the **T** should be in upper-case). [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ehsant/ca1kg7g7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now realised that I was missing `this`. It now works.

I have changed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.start").next().slidetoggle("li");
});
```

to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".parent").click(function(){
    $(this).next('li').slideToggle(250);
  });
});
```